# Determining Inconsistency of (first-order) Non-linear System of Equations

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, linear-algebra, finite-fields

Is there a way  I can figure out what values of the coefficients of some system of non-linear equations makes the system inconsistent?

Take the following system of equations as an example.  The  unknowns are $(y_0,..., y_8)$.  I do not have fixed values for the coefficients   $a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,u,v,w$, so I just want to know which  values of  $a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,u,v,w$ make the system inconsistent.

Note that in the example I am using the system is underdetermined as I have 9 unknowns and only 8 equations.

$$\begin{array}\\
u*y_5 +  e*y_7  - e + b*y_2*y_0 + c*y_2 + w*y_0  =0\\
d*y_5 + f*y_7 -  f +  a*y_2 + v*y_0 = 0\\
u*y_6 - w*y_7  + b*y_3*y_0 + b*y_2*y_1 + c*y_3  + w*y_1 =  0\\
u*y_8 - c*y_7 + b*y_4*y_0 + c*y_4 =0\\
d*y_8 - a*y_7  + a*y_4 = 0\\
d*y_6 - v*y_7  + a*y_3    + v*y_1  = 0\\
b*y_7 -  b*y_4*y_1 = 0\\
y_1 = 0\\
\end{array}$$

Any hints or help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Why the "finite fields" tag?

Comment: @Gerry Myerson as a matter of fact I need the solutions over a finite field

Comment: @jeq yes y_1 is 0. I know I could have modified the other equations accordingly rather than having to add the last equation ...

Comment: Then maybe you should say so, Jousha.

Comment: As I understand your question, your system of equations will be inconsistent if it has no solutions. However, it is clear that setting $y_i = 0$ for all $i$ gives a solution, whatever the values of the unfixed coefficients. Hence, since the system always has at least one solution, I don't see how it can ever be inconsistent. Perhaps you need to refine your question to avoid this trivial answer.

Comment: @Igor Khavkine: Not quite right. Note that for instance in the first two equations you have constant terms in the equations. So a trivial solution will only be a valid solution if the coefficients involved in those constant terms are also 0.

Comment: Ah, yes you're right. Sorry, they were very well hidden. I missed them even after double checking!